# My tables are working fine if I add data in the access file but not when the data is entered through the application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

My tables are working fine if I add data in the access file but not when the data is entered through the application.

I've tried disconnecting and reconnecting dataset. I've also deleted dataset & created again, Still the same error.

```vb
Imports System.IO 
Private Sub VehicleEntry_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.DetailsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DbDataSet.Details)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        DetailsBindingSource.AddNew()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        On Error GoTo SaveErr
        DetailsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        DetailsTableAdapter.Update(DbDataSet)
        MessageBox.Show("New User Added Successfully!")
SaveErr:
        Exit Sub
    End Sub
End Class
```

No Error messages received.

Comment: In a world of Try-Catch, you should never use `On Error Goto ...`

Comment: Do you have an UpdateCommand for your DetailsTableAdapter (check by setting a breakpoint)?

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn tried that but still the same error